# gorm v1 foreignKey Self model association

Tags: go, go-gorm

About gorm v1 I have some questions about the definition of the autocorrelation correlation model. I hope everyone can help me out

```
type Player struct {
    ID int gorm:"primary_key" // id
    PID int gorm:"column:p_id;index;" 
    IsMain bool gorm:"column:is_main;default:false"
    PInfo *Player  gorm:"foreignKey:PID;association_foreignkey:ID;association_autoupdate:false;association_autocreate:false" 
}
```

Here, my PID is used to associate with the ID of the superior, but when querying, Preload ("PInfo") used the ID of this data to match the PID of the superior. According to my settings in the document, there should be no problem. Why does the opposite result appear

Let me try  Change

```
foreignKey:PID;association_foreignkey:ID
```

```
oreignKey:ID;association_foreignkey:PID
```

actually works correctly, but it seems to be the opposite of what is described in the document. Is it because of my pointer problem